# How to multiply Array of object Based on Quantity To Create new Rows?

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, html-table, mern, tablerow

How can i Multiply array object inside 'AddNewRow' function so i can create new rows based on quantity, if user insert '3' in quantity column and click on 'add' Button then '3' rows should be created.

How can i do This Please help me.

**This Is My AddNewRow Function**

```
/*For Handling addrow button event */
  const addNewRow = () => {
    try {
      if (
        GetLastProdId === "" ||
        GetLastPrice === "" ||
        GetLastProdSrno === "" ||
        GetLastProd_Status === "ProDataWarranty" && GetLastProDataWarrentyInPrcnt === "NULL"
      ) {
        console.log("empty fields!!!!!");
        setFill(true);
      } else if (GetLastProdSrno === GetSecondLastProd_Srno) {
        setProdSrnoSame(true);
        console.log("Prod SrNo same!!!");
      } else {
        setProdSrnoSame(false);

        setProduct_Details((prevState) => [
          ...prevState,

//** Want This Object get multiplied By Clicking.
         {
            index: Math.random(),
            billId: BillIdFetch,
            prodId: "",
            price: "",
            prod_SrNo: "",
            discount: "0",
            Qty:"1",
            Prod_Status: "NULL",
            proData_warranty_In_Prcnt: "NULL",
            Credit_Note: "NULL",
            Replacement: "NULL",
          },
        ]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array an add as many object copies to it as you want:

```
/*For Handling addrow button event */
const addNewRow = () => {
  try {
    if (
      GetLastProdId === '' ||
      GetLastPrice === '' ||
      GetLastProdSrno === '' ||
      (GetLastProd_Status === 'ProDataWarranty' &&
        GetLastProDataWarrentyInPrcnt === 'NULL')
    ) {
      console.log('empty fields!!!!!');
      setFill(true);
    } else if (GetLastProdSrno === GetSecondLastProd_Srno) {
      setProdSrnoSame(true);
      console.log('Prod SrNo same!!!');
    } else {
      setProdSrnoSame(false);

      // Object to be multiplied
      const obj = {
        billId: BillIdFetch,
        prodId: '',
        price: '',
        prod_SrNo: '',
        discount: '0',
        Qty: '1',
        Prod_Status: 'NULL',
        proData_warranty_In_Prcnt: 'NULL',
        Credit_Note: 'NULL',
        Replacement: 'NULL',
      };

      const addedObjs = [];

      // Add as many `obj` as the quantity inserted by the user
      for (let i = 0; i < multiplier; i++) addedObjs.push({ ...obj, index: Math.random(), });

      setProduct_Details((prevState) => [
        ...prevState,
        ...addedObjs
      ]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @lpizzinidev But i get Warning  when i Put your code in my code it works fine but when check console it showing me this Warning, I pass 'index' as a key in render so if i create new row using this method it coping same row as 1st row:- 

Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0.8625204077152724`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: i Add 3 row first row is default row after click on add 3 rows created with same index.
Console Output :- https://screenrec.com/share/7tKbsBFYLT

Comment: @AdnanShaikh Move the logic for `index` creation on the pushed objects (see edited answer)

Comment: Can you Help me in this Problem also :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308098/how-to-display-duplicate-array-values-only-once-in-react-js